# Queued tasks and possible unloads before completion

Tags: swift, asynchronous, queue, task, dispatch-async

I am making a software with a background web database. I am loading data from the web to table views and collection views. Sometimes these are bigger photos. All these data load are running async, so the table is loaded, for example, but without the photos and the photos are loaded in a separate queue. I am uncertain what happens, if I dismiss the view which is loading the photos, before the photo is downloaded. Here is the code which is loading a data as an example.

```
        DispatchWork = DispatchWorkItem(block: {
        let thisData = try? Data(contentsOf: thisURL!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.jSonData = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: thisData!, options: []) as! [[String: String]]
            self.counter = self.jSonData.count
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async(execute: DispatchWork!)
```

This is working, but I was not able to test so far what happens if I dismiss the view before everything is loaded. I have tried to the DispatchWork.cancel() in the deinit section, but it was not called at all.

I am afraid that changing views might cause that the running task tries to update the view with the downloaded data when the view is not displayed already and the program will crash than.

Is there a good practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

As your code currently stands, it would just continue to do what it intended. The async closures are not using weak references to self so they can keep a strong reference until the async task is complete if I remember rightly. So the image downloads and stuff will continue as normal and update the image views when done, when all of your async tasks that were running when you closed the VC are complete, the View controller should be deallocated.

For better memory management you should use `[weak self]` in your async closures in the view controller, so that when the view controller is dismissed there are no strong references keeping it in memory. Its quite likely that any downloads started will continue until they complete, or error out. They wont cause the view controller to stay in memory and run the closures when they get their response though.

Comment: Could you add to my code, how do you mean this? My concern is that the Data(contentOf: thisURL!) line might wait for the data for a long time and in the meantime the view is already unloaded and the code should not be continued.